# how to make an automatic redirect to 404 every $slug that is not in views

Tags: php, laravel

here is my code, i need to redirect every $slug that is not in views to 404 page automaticly

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getPages($slug)
    {
        return view($slug);
    }

    public function getHome()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far and what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
view()->exists($slug)
```

to check wheater the view exist or not

if not present you can use below snippet to redirect to 404

```
return abort(404);
```

complete code:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getPages($slug) 
    {
        if(view()->exists($slug))
          return view($slug);
        else
          return abort(404);
    }
    public function getHome()
    {

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `View` facade. The `exists` method will return `true` if the view exists:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View; // add this line
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getPages($slug) 
    {
          if (View::exists($slug)) { // check here
            return view($slug);
          }

      return abort(404); // redirect to 404 page

    }
    public function getHome()
    {

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

References:

[Laravel -> View -> Determining If A View Exists](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#creating-views)

[Laravel -> Error Handling -> Http Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/errors#http-exceptions)

Comment: how to add multiple error to redirect like 404, 403, and 500

Comment: Same as above `return abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');`

Answer (score 0):

there is 1 simple way to do if view is not avaliable or mistake in write url to send them to page 404.

Using the Route::fallback method, you may define a route that will be executed when no other route matches the incoming request

requests will automatically render a "404" page via your application's exception handler.

The fallback route should always be the last route registered by your application.

write in your apps route file(web.php) in the last.

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('your_404_page_name');
});
```